# Ask Siri to change my wake up alarm time

Tags: ios, siri, alarm

In previous versions of iOS, I was able to ask Siri on either my iPhone or HomePod mini to “change my wake up time to 7 AM”.

In recent versions of iOS, this feature disappeared. Now Siri says “you don’t have any alarms” when in fact I do have a wake up alarm set daily.

Is there some way to convince Siri to change the wake up alarm time?

Comment: So, what have you tried so far? Resetting the alarm? Deleting the alarm and asking Siri to put a new one? then asking Siri to reset the target time?

Comment: Perhaps you can provide some additional details of what you'd specifically like to have edited?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

> Hey Siri, change my X:XXam alarm to X:XXam

Or, if you have a label for your alarm:

> Hey Siri, change the [label] alarm to X:XXam

This works perfectly on iOS and iPadOS 17.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't appear to be something that Siri can fix.  I've personally tried modifying this via Siri and via Shortcuts, an neither would allow the change to propagate.  Here is my theory....

First, the "wake alarm" appears in two distinct places:  *Alarms and Focus*. Secondly, it is impossible to access Focus setting via an alternate method like Siri or Shortcuts.  The only way I was able to gain access was manually through the App itself.

I can see how earlier versions of iOS allowed you to change Alarm date and settings, but things like "Wake/Sleep" get integrated with focus. I've been dealing with this issue since at least iOS15

Perhaps you can provide some additional details of what you'd specifically like to have edited?